# How to encode a PKCE code for OAuth public client with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to generate a 43-octet (Byte) string to use as code verifier for OAuth authentication with PowerShell as described in [RFC7636](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636).

> 4. Protocol
>
> 4.1.  Client Creates a Code Verifier
>
> The client first creates a code verifier, "code_verifier", for each
> OAuth 2.0 [RFC6749] Authorization Request, in the following manner:
>
> code_verifier = high-entropy cryptographic random STRING using the
> unreserved characters [A-Z] / [a-z] / [0-9] / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
> from Section 2.3 of [RFC3986], with a minimum length of 43 characters
> and a maximum length of 128 characters.
>
> ABNF for "code_verifier" is as follows.
>
> code-verifier = 43*128unreserved    unreserved = ALPHA / DIGIT /
> "-" / "." / "_" / "~"    ALPHA = %x41-5A / %x61-7A    DIGIT = %x30-39
>
> NOTE: The code verifier SHOULD have enough entropy to make it
> impractical to guess the value.  **It is RECOMMENDED that the output of
> a suitable random number generator be used to create a 32-octet
>
> sequence.  The octet sequence is then base64url-encoded to produce a
>
> 43-octet URL safe string to use as the code verifier**.

I found that using the RNGCryptoServiceProvider class is more likely to generate a high-entropy random number but when I convert it into a base64 string, it has undesired characters.

```
$RandomNumberGenerator = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider
    $Bytes = New-Object Byte[] 32
    $RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes($Bytes)
    [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
```

How can I generate a compliant base64 string using the RNGCryptoServiceProvider?

Comment: Apparently, I require a 43 character base64 string without "+" or "/".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want Url-safe Base64 encoding, which can be done by utilizing the [[System.Web.HttpServerUtility]::UrlTokenEncode()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.urltokenencode?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_HttpServerUtility_UrlTokenEncode_System_Byte___) method in System.Web.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web

$RandomNumberGenerator = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider
$Bytes = New-Object Byte[] 32
$RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes($Bytes)
[System.Web.HttpServerUtility]::UrlTokenEncode($Bytes)
```

The last character(s) may be padding character(s). For 'normal' Base64, the `=` is used.
The `UrlTokenEncode()` uses a different (url-safe) alphabet where the padding character is `1`
It should be quite safe to trim off that last padding character with:

```
([System.Web.HttpServerUtility]::UrlTokenEncode($Bytes)).TrimEnd("1")
```

or

```
([System.Web.HttpServerUtility]::UrlTokenEncode($Bytes)).Substring(0, 43)
```

to ensure you get a 43 character string.